# Solving for common ratio when given limiting sum and first term

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I go about solving for the common ratio, when limiting sum is 5 and the 1st term is 3

I know the formula is: $a/(1-r) $

5 = $3/(1-r )$

Where do I go from here

Comment: Multiply both sides by $1-r$

Comment: So are you referencing to a geometric series, here? Or what? Also, do you mean
$$
5 = \frac{3}{1-r}
$$
?

Comment: That's what I mean matti

Comment: So would that be
$5(1-r)$ = 3(1-r)

Comment: How many terms do you have in your summation ?

Comment: 1 term available

Answer (score 1):

We recall: the sum of an infinite  geometric series, with ratio $r$ ($|r|<1$), and first term $a$, is given by

$$a+ar+ar^2 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n = \frac{a}{1-r}$$

You are given that the limiting sum is $5$, and the first term is $3$. You want the ratio $r$, and thus wish to solve for $r$ below:

$$5 = \frac{3}{1-r}$$

We first multiply by $(1-r)$ on both sides, obtaining

$$5(1-r) = \frac{3}{1-r} \cdot (1-r)$$

On the left-hand side, we distribute the $r$, and on the right-hand side the $(1-r)$ factor cancels. Combining both steps gives us a linear equation which is easy to solve:

$$5-5r = 3$$

Subtract $5$ from both sides, and then divide by $(-5)$. This isolates $r$, giving us

$$r = \frac{3-5}{-5} = \frac 2 5$$

---

You can also treat this problem more generally. Let's call the limiting sum $S$, and the first term and ratio as before. We can solve for $r$ in the equation below:

$$S = \frac{a}{1-r}$$

By following a largely identical process as to before (I leave the algebra up to you), we can see

$$r = \frac{a-S}{-S} = \frac{S-a}{S}$$

This itself merits a simplification by splitting up the fraction at the right-hand side, and thus

$$r = \frac S S - \frac a S = 1 - \frac a S$$

You can see an identical result to your problem if $a=3,S=5$.